# MongoDB find documents based on array of values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I have one collection, called "games" whose documents store the ids of the owners of games.

```
{
    "owner" : "88878b6c25c167d"
}
{
    "owner" : "88878b6c25c167d"
}
{
    "owner" : "af565f77f73469b"
}
```

Then I have another collection called "users".

```
{
    "id" : "af565f77f73469b"
}
{
    "id" : "a881335e1d4cf17"
}
{
    "id" : "aa3ce3f7767c46b"
}
{
    "id" : "d19e52c0bd78bcb"
}
{
    "id" : "88878b6c25c167d"
}
```

So the first query I do retrieves the owners of all the games and stores those values in an array.`['88878b6c25c167d', '88878b6c25c167d', 'af565f77f73469b']`
The second query I want to perform should retrieve the documents of the users with the corresponding IDs. Previously I had used this query:

```
db.users.find({'id':
    {'$in': [
        '88878b6c25c167d',
        '88878b6c25c167d',
        'af565f77f73469b'
    ]}})
```

Here's the problem with this: It does not return duplicate documents if a user is listed twice, as above. Instead I just get one. This breaks my application. How can I make sure that each owner returns a document?

Comment: Keep the list, then walk through the resulting documents from the `find` operation, and do the association then.

Comment: sounds like the application is broken.

Comment: @Kamsky: Why do you think the application is broken?

Comment: @WiredPrairie: So there's no way to do this in Mongo?

Comment: Return duplicate documents? No. I'd certainly not want it to behave that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB works perfectly fine --- it finds all user, whose `id-s` are contained in the array.

Do not know the broader context of your needs (maybe tell us what you want to achieve -- not what is *wrong*?), but if you want to have an association between  `games` and `users` something like that may be suitable:

1. after retrieving collection of games; just create an auxiliary hash map (normal JS object) that for given `owner id` will return the array of its games.
2. retrieve info about users who are owners.
3. if you want to know, which games belong to particular `user` just pass her `id` to data structure from 1. and get the arrays with games.

Is it what you were looking for? Do you need help with 1.?

Comment: Thanks, I've resolved this issue through some server-side JS code. I would have liked to have been able to accomplish my task through a query, but the work around was suitable.